# C# retrieving username and password from data table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am new to C#. I am using a VS2010 and LINQ.
Heres my problem..
I have a login page, with 2 textboxes and confirm button. When the button is pressed, application should check the username and password from table uporabniki and if it is correct, then redirect..

How can I store all usernames and passwords to List and than loop through the list and check for a match?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    WebApplication7.linqDataContext db = new WebApplication7.linqDataContext();

    var users = from usr in db.uporabnikis select usr.username;

    List<String> upo = new List<String>();
    upo = (List<String>) users;
}
```

Thank you, 
Beni

Comment: Instead of storing passwords, why not store a HASH of the password, and then check the hashes?

Comment: Please do not store passwords in plaintext.  I am really tired of websites run by people who have no bloody clue on how to store this type of information.  If you are able to retrieve a password and display it to the user, then you are doing it wrong, its should not be possible to retrieve a user's password.

Answer (score 3):

You should just add the check to the query, something like this should do:

```
   WebApplication7.linqDataContext db = new WebApplication7.linqDataContext();

   bool validLogin = (from usr in db.uporabnikis
                where usr.username == txtUserName.Text and 
                      usr.password == txtPassword.Text
                select true).SingleOrDefault();

   if(validLogin)
       // Do stuff
```

I do agree with the comment of nonnb above though, you should store a hash and not the plain text password.

Comment: Hello and thanx for quick reply. I am making this page for myself to learn simple stuff about C#.  Thanx for solution it works,but  i want to know how can i store them to list :)

Comment: Hey I never noticed you could 'select true' in your linq statement like that. Not sure I like it, as I mis-read it at first pass, but it might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't store passwords in databases, that is dangerous. Store a hash.
2. Don't obtain a list in the first place, you've already got a database, and it knows how to find individual rows.

You want something more like:

```
var userInfo = (from usr in db.uporabnikis where usr.username == Request.Form["username"] select {usr.username, usr.passwordHash, usr.salt).FirstOrDefault();

bool loggedIn = passwordHash == HashPassword(usr.username, usr.salt, Request.Form["password"]);
```

Etc...

Comment: iv done it! Check with md5 and adding new user..stored md5 hash in table.

Comment: What are you doing the MD5 of? Ideally it should be on username + password + something random or else username + password + something unique to your system. Just hash password and an attack can change their password to "password" etc. and look for people with the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebApplication7.linqDataContext db = new WebApplication7.linqDataContext();

        var users = from usr in db.uporabnikis
                    select usr.username,usr.password;

        bool result = false;

        foreach(var user in users)
        {
            if(user.username.Equals("usernametocheck") && user.password.Equals("passwordtocheck"))
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(result)
        {
            //code to redirect
        }
        else
        {
            //Display error
        }

    }
```

Or You can try this

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebApplication7.linqDataContext db = new WebApplication7.linqDataContext();

        int recordCount = 0;
        recordCount  = db.uporabnikis.where(x => x.username == "usernametocheck" && x.password = "passwordtocheck").Count();



        if (recordCount > 0)
        {
            //code to redirect
        }
        else
        {
            //Display error
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `users` variable implements an interface called `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` in your case equals `string`.

To get a `List<string>` from an `IEnumerable<string>` the simplest route is to use the LINQ extension method `ToList()`, so:

```
List<String> upo =users.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be storing any passwords using Hash. Such as MD5, and checking against that.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

 using (MD5 hash = MD5.Create())
        {password = GetMd5Hash(hash,passwordString}
```